# Are there add-ons for Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

Does Mail on Mac OS have any add-ons applicable ? Such as the ones possible in website-based Gmail application ?

I would like a feature that allows me to UNDO a sent message. Gmail has an addon which accomplishes this.

Is it possible in the Mail app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plug-ins available for Apple Mail.  Some are plug-ins, some are AppleScripts.

You could easily accomplish this via AppleScript.  For example, here's a [set of AppleScripts for Apple Mail that includes a delay send one](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/9178/mail-scripts), although the author of those scripts notes that they haven't been updated recently and might not work with more current versions of OS X.  You'll have to try it and see.  Since it's an AppleScript, if you're willing to get your hands dirty, you can edit it to better meet your needs.

Another option is [Mail Scheduler](http://www.mrose.nl/mailscheduler), which includes delayed send as well as several other related items.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually quite a lot of addons for mail.app (See [here](http://www.tikouka.net/mailapp/) and [here](http://www.hawkwings.net/plugins.htm)—unfortunately these are both cobweb sites).

Technically it's not possible to "unsend" an e-mail message. It would be possible to queue up a message that would be sent automatically a few minutes later, and that would give you time to catch those mistakes you normally catch the second you hit "send". (This is actually how Eudora worked.) But I'm not aware of anything that does this for mail.app.